# Jquery - prevent default action of <a> on first click, allow default action on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How would I prevent the default action of an `<a>` on the first click (in order so that a tooltip is shown), then on the second click have the user directed to the value of the `href` attribute set on the  element?

HTML

```
<a id="second" href="https://www.test.com/"  title="" class="customtooltip c_tool2"   data-original-title="data del toolltip numero 2">tooltip</a>
```

Jquery

```
var t = $('.c_tool2'), b = $('a[href^="http');

b.click(function(e){
  if(t.length > 0){
    e.preventDefault();
    t.tooltip('show');
  } else {
    // on second click direct user to value of href 
  }
});
```

Comment: Unrelated, but this seems like a bad UX. When I click a link it should do linky things. I'd use a hover for the tooltip instead, like every other tooltip.

Comment: The context of this if for Android touch devices, to match the default behaviour of iOS devices and hopefully give a consistent UX. If not the first tap on Android takes the user to the link, they will only see a popover for a split second (which I feel is useless). iOS is first tap shown tooltip, second tap follow link. I've spend a lot of time considering how to make this intuitive and consistent across iOS and Android devices.

Comment: Fair enough, although for me on iOS clicking a link takes me to the link.

Comment: What if the link has a tooltip applied? Specifically using Bootstrap v3.3.5 - http://www.the-session.co.uk/dev_standalone/ tap on the 'second tooltip' located in the red header. The behaviour should be first tap tooltip, second tap link direct.

Comment: Maybe this should rather been seen as an indicator that such “tooltips” are not good UX to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there will be multiple elements, using a common counter will not work. You can use counter on individual element using `data-*` attribute

Also, the selector to select the anchors is incorrect.

```
var t = $('.c_tool2'),
    b = $('a[href^="http"]'); // <-- Added "] to make it correct

b.click(function (e) {
    // Get the counter for clicked element
    var clickCount = parseInt($(this).data('count'), 10) || 0;

    // If counter is zero i.e. for the first click
    if (!clickCount) {
        // Update the value of the counter
        $(this).data('count', ++clickCount);
        t.tooltip('show');

        // Prevent the default action of the page redirection
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    // Else, follow the default action
});
```

Comment: So `clickCount++` will assign the zero to it and then it will get incremented. Eventually you coded to make the redirect happens in the third click. you should use `++clickCount` here.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make use of `.data()` instead of polluting the global scope with counters,

```
b.click(function(e) {
  if(!$(this).data("flag")) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).data("flag",true);
    t.tooltip('show');
  } else {
    // on second click direct user to value of href 
  }
});
```